# How to install KVM(kernal virtual machine) without any OS in a PC?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtualization, openstack, kvm

Can we install KVM in a machine directly, with out any OS? if possible can you please suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

KVM is a Type-2 hypervisor. KVM stands for Kernel based Virtual Machine. By design, it cannot run stand-alone.

Google for *Type-1*, *native*, or *bare-metal* hypervisors to find hypervisor that run without OS. If you are looking for an open-source Type-1 hypervisor, give *Xen* a try.

Comment: Can we install linux kernal in a machine without any OS like CentOS, Ubuntu etc?

Comment: Absolutely! But it wouldn't be useful without system libraries. 

What you can do is to install KVM on top of a lightweight Linux distribution without graphical desktop.